# DP Problem, best split of continous segments

Tags: dynamic-programming

I’m thinking on how to solve dynamic programming problem.

The problem is:
input: r,c,minWidth,maxWidth and matrix of size r*c.

Imagine, each columns represents line of barcode. Each line can have different width - segment of columns with same color(in our example 1 = black, 0 = white). If w_i is size of segment i, then minWidth <= w_i <= maxWidth. Also colors of segments must alternate(you cant have 2 segments of same colors in a row -> it can cause that this two segments of same color are above maxWidth limit, which we doesnt want.
Note that barcode can start/end also with 0-column.

The task is to find a number of pixel changes(from 0 to 1 and vise versa) to valid barcode described above.

To ilustrate a problem:
Example of input and bitmap can be

```
6 6 2 3
0 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 1 0
1 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 1 1
```

The output of algorithm should be a minimum number of changes in bitmap. Optimal should be...

```
1st and 2nd column is covered with ones - 5 changes
3rd and 4th column is covered with zeros - 4 changes
5th and 6th column is covered with ones - 8 changes
Therefore sum is 17.
```

Any idea how to solve it?

I tried use 3D array [columns][color(0,1)][width] which are filled in for cycle.

```
For [0][1][0], [0][0][0] = 0
for c 1..s:
  for w 1..maxWidth:
    if w > minWidth:
      [c][0][1] = min([c][0][1], [c-1][1][w-1] + toWhite[i-1])
      [c][1][1] = min([c][1][1], [c-1][0][w-1] + s - toWhite[i-1])

    [c][0][w] = min([c][0][w], [c-1][0][w-1] + toWhite[i-1])
    [c][1][w] = min([c][0][w], [c-1][1][w-1] + s - toWhite[i-1])
```

Where solution will be in min([s][0 or 1][w>=minwidth])

Comment: Hi. Could you please reword the sentence *"Which is 17(1,2 col = 1; 3,4 = 0, 5-6 = 1), also 1,2,3 = 1 and 4,5,6 = 0 is 17."* so that it makes more sense? I don't know what *"1,2 col = 1"* means and my religion forbids me from reading minds on saturday.

Comment: Also can you please reword the two sentences *"For input matrix find number of changes(one -> zero + zero -> one) to make every columns contains same number. Width of each segment should be >= f && <= t."* ? What does "contains same number" mean? And what "segments" are you talking about?

Comment: Did some repair for better understanding.

Comment: Sorry, I understand even less than before now.

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence of your question, but hopefully I've understood the question enough overall to answer it properly. Tell me if it's not what you wanted.

Comment: @Stef I think the sentence "Which is 17(1,2 col = 1; 3,4 = 0, 5-6 = 1), also 1,2,3 = 1 and 4,5,6 = 0 is 17" means that, in the fnial solution, the columns one and two should be filled with ones (which means changing 5 entry), the columns three and four should contain zeros (which means changing 4 entries), and the final two columns should contain ones (which means changing 8 entries), for a total of 5+4+8=17 changes overall in the matrix.

Comment: @Stef (my religion allows me to read minds on saturdays :))

Comment: @jthulhu yea, you are right with that :D Also updated code i have.

Answer (score 2):

First, for each column, compute how expensive it would be to make it all ones or all zeros. For instance, on the matrix

```
0 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 1 0
1 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 1 1
```

The result would be

```
5 0 5 3 3 5
```

for the cost of turning these columns to ones, and

```
1 6 1 3 3 1
```

the cost of turning these columns to zeros (it's the complement to `6` so you don't *need* to store these values, you can compute them on the fly). We will call these two tables `C₀` and `C₁` respectively.

Then, we will use dynamic programming to fill two tables, `C` and `W`. `C[i]` represents the minimum cost for solving your problem up to the `i`-th column (zero indexed), and `W[i]` represents the width of the bar of ones starting at column `i` in the solution that minimizes `C[i]`, or `0` if in that solution the column `i` is filled with zeroes.

For every `i<f`, `C[i] = sum(C₀[j] for j in [0, i])` (I will use a Python-like notation for sums, which is, IMO, quite readable independently of whether you know Python or not). Indeed, up to the column `i`, we don't have enough space to put a column full of ones, so we must convert everything to zeros. Similarly, `W[i] = 0`.

Subsequently, `C[i] = min(min(sum(C₁[j] for j in [i-w+1, i]) + C₀[i-w] + C[i-w] for w in [f, min(i, t)]), C₀[i] + C[i-1])` (assuming that accesses at negative indexes in arrays always return `0`, which is in general a bad idea but works here). The idea is that, either you chose to fill with ones the columns `i-w` to `i`, where `w` is the width of the bar, in which case you must also fill with zeros the *previous* column `i-w`, or you fill in with zeros. `W[i]` must be filled according to which value was the minimum in the expression above. If it was a `min(sum(C₁[j] for j in [i-w+1, i]) + C₀[i-w] + C[i-w-1]`, for a certain `w`, then `W[i] = w` . Otherwise, `W[i] = 0`.

Finally, the total cost is given by the last element in `C`, and the actual solution can be reconstructed using `W`, by reading backward: start with `i = c-1` and, while `i≥0`, if `W[i] = 0`, fill the `i`-th columns with zeros and decrement `i`; otherwise fill the columns `i-W[i]` to `i` with ones, `i-W[i]-1` with zeros, and set `i = i-W[i]-2`.

Note that this is still a bit expensive because you compute over and over the sums of contiguous values in `C₁` and `C₀`. To avoid that, you can precompute, for `C₁` for instance, `C'₁`, for which `C'₁[i] = sum(C[j] for j in [0, i])` (which can be computed starting with `C'₁[0] = C₁[0]`, and `C'₁[i+1] = C'₁[i] + C₁[i+1]`).

Then, we can compute `sum(C₁[i] for i in [j, k])` with `C'₁[k]-C'₁[j-1]` (again, access out of bounds return zero).

Also note that, if you don't need to reconstruct the solution, just to give its cost (as it seems to be in your case), you can forget the construction of `W` altogether, I just gave it for the sake of completeness.

In your example, the final cost for each column `C` would be `1 5 6 9 12 17`, and therefore the total cost is `17`, which is what we expected.

Comment: I think i dont understand how C works, because as you write: "C would be 1 5 6 9 12 17" the 2nd and 3rd should be 6, 7 or am i wrong ?

Comment: @ajWee let's take the second element of `C`, `5`. It corresponds to the cost of the solution for the matrix which contains only the first two columns of the matrix given in the example. In this case, the solution would be to convert everything to ones, changing the five zeros in the first column to ones. Hence `C[1] = 5`. Similarly, if we consider just the first three columns, then a solution would be to convert the first two columns to ones, and the third one to zeros, requiring `6` changes overall.

Comment: I realize I did mix up the some indices in one of the formulas in the answer, now it will probably work better

Comment: Also in your solution are you counting on that, that barcode can ends and starts with white color ?

Comment: @ajWee yes, the only constraint is that black columns must be in contiguous blocks whose width is between `minWidth` and `maxWidth`.

Comment: can i ask you for implementation code ? i have trouble to implement your idea. also i forget to tell you, that contiguous blocks of 0 must be between min and maxWidth

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254117/discussion-between-ajwee-and-jthulhu).